# Overwrite Jboss jar with Maven dependencies

Tags: jboss6.x

Hi we have to use **JBoss 6.4**, But when I try to execute my code it fails due to missing method and works fine with **JBoss 6.3** and **JBoss 7**

the `setSSLContext` method became available in v4.5 of `HttpClientBuiler`.
**JBOSS 6.4** comes bundled with *v4.3.6JBOSS 6.4* comes bundled with v4.3.6

So if I use version 4.5.2 via maven, does it override all the **JBoss** methods. If not what is the solution?

I want to use **JBoss 6.4** only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to want to use any other version of components which  is not bundled with specific Jboss release, then you can create it as module dependencies and use it. Make sure that you should exclude the particular version of components which bundle with JBoss inside jboss-deployment-structure.xml file

see the link: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Comment: I have not installed the Jboss, I jave extracted the JBoss 6.4 zip file and using it. Could you provide an alternative solution in this case